# unwrapping a function swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I can't get this function to work in response to an `indexPath` being selected.

When I add a breakpoint to the line in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` it breaks but when I add one where it function is in the viewscontroller class it won't break. It's as if the information is being sent but cannot reach its destination. I get no error in my console and I've looked over everything multiple times.

Could this be an xcode bug or have I missed something?

Here is where I reference the class it's located in

```
var viewsController: ViewsController?
```

Here's my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    viewsController?.scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item)
    print(indexPath.item)

}
```

And here is the function itself

```
func scrollToMenuIndex(_ menuIndex: Int) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: menuIndex, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition(), animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Everything works it's as if I can't segue the data. *Note this is being done programmatically without storyboards.

Comment: if scrollToMenuIndex is in same class just scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item) would be enough !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewsController` is declared but not initialized. So it is unknown which class method is called.

```
var viewsController: ViewsController?
```

if `scrollToMenuIndex` is in same class just `scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item)` would be enough !! If its not in same view controller, you need to initialize `viewsController` as

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
     let viewsController= storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
     viewsController?.scrollToMenuIndex(indexPath.item)
     print(indexPath.item)
  }
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: viewsController is where my rootViewController is. What I'm trying to build is a controller similar to the youtube tab bar. So you select a cell in the tab bar and it scrolls the collection view to the appropriate cell. These are two separate kinds of UICollectionViewCells in two separate viewControllers in different classes.

Comment: is your viewsController  initialized ??

Answer (score 0):

The reference while valid was returning nil for viewsController.

So in the closure that referenced the collection view that housed the cells that I was using for my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` (located in viewsController),

I had to add c.viewsController = self and that fixed it.

I'll have to take a look at what the documentation says about this. I'll update my answer then if no one has yet to explain this behavior.